# Adding a network share to Plex server as a library

Tags: mount, cifs, nas, plex

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtualbox to test out my use cases before taking the plunge and installing it on my machine, trying to get plex server configured to communicate with my Asustor NAS and running into some issues. I have cifs-utils installed, I have added the following line to /etc/fstab

`//*NAS-IP*/Media /media/*user*/NAS cifs credentials=/home/*user*/password,iocharset=utf8 0 0`

where *NAS-IP * is the ip address of the NAS, Media being a folder with subdirectories for movies/music etc, *user * is just my ubuntu username.

I don't think I'm too far wrong as I can see the network share in the Files directory and relevant subfolders and access my media from there, and the mount persists after reboot, where I run into trouble is trying to add libraries on Plex server. It can "see" the network share /*NAS-IP */Media but not the sub folders for the specific media types, yet I can see them in Ubuntu Files. Hence, no media appearing in Plex. Is there something I'm doing wrong with mounting the network share? or somewhere else I'm going wrong, I hope I've been clear enough with my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing to a specific media folder, and change your credentials file to a dot_filename like ".password". //*NAS-IP*/Media/Music /media/*user*/Music cifs credentials=/home/*user*/.password,iocharset=utf8 0 0

Comment: Also chmod your .password file.

Comment: Hi heynnema, I targeted the specific sub folder like you suggested with Music, and as before I could mount the drive/folder in Files no problem and see it in Plex, but it's not adding media from the folder into the plex library. I did the dot_filename to hide the credentials file as well. I'm unsure what chmod my password file means, I've really  only been using ubuntu for a couple of days now, but I'll look into it.

Comment: I did get this error after saving /etc/fstab in gedit

(gedit:14321): Tepl-WARNING **: 15:02:22.272: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using chmod on the /media/user/NAS directories one at a time, which enabled the plex user to access the share and process the media into its libraries.

Thanks heynnema for a prod in the right direction.

Comment: Good job! That's an appropriate fix.